# How to show post based on user that's logged in?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm making an android app and want to show my Post based on the user that's logged in.

[image: This is my user's database structure]

[image: This is my post's database structure]

Does anyone know how to show Post that have the same String (in this case the string from the child 'fakultas') as the String in User (the child 'admin')? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps

`postsRef.orderByChild("fakultas").equalTo("Fak. tecknik")`

**Sample code :**

````
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
    System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey());
  }

  // ...
});```
````